# How to make Spring Boot's GET return JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I have a little beginner's mistake in my project. I'm building a RESTful service with Spring Boot and my get method doesn't work.

---

I made an Entity called Project, that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class ProjectDto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="caption")
    private String caption;

    ..GETTERS AND SETTERS FOLLOW..
```

---

, than I created ProjectRepository like this:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<ProjectDto, Long> {

    public static final String GET_TIMELINE_PROJECT_CAPTIONS_QUERY = "SELECT 
    p.id, p.caption FROM ProjectDto p ORDER BY p.creationDate DESC";

    @Query(GET_TIMELINE_PROJECT_CAPTIONS_QUERY)
    public List<ProjectDto> getTimelineProjectCaptions();

}
```

---

..and a Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/project")
public class ProjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;


    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/timeline", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ProjectDto> getTimelineProjectCaptions() {
        return projectRepository.getTimelineProjectCaptions();
    }

}
```

---

but that gives`[[5,"sddf"],[3,"asdf"],[2,"gb"],[1,"bg"]]`, which apparently isn't JSON

Answer (score 3):

It is JSON. It's an array of arrays, which is what your query actually returns.

If you want an array of ProjectDto objects, the query should be

```
SELECT p FROM ProjectDto p ORDER BY p.creationDate DESC
```

Not sure why you're naming your entities with a Dto suffix. Entities are not DTOs. A DTO is a Data Transfer Object, i.e. an object specifically designed for data transfer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, now it really returns JSON. I would like to only select the two values though (the table has more columns and there are also more variables in ProjectDto that I didn't mention here, is there a way to do that? Just not to select unnecessary columns..

Comment: Also.. by the way, how is it not a DTO? It carries the table's date, which I thought was what makes a DTO.. Don't want to argue, I simply don't understand it.

Comment: martin k. an @Entity is the representation of a portion of a database; when inside a transactional method, changing a property will result in changing a column in the database. It *can* be used to carry data to other layers, even up to the front-end, but it's not what is designed for. DTO, on the other side, is an (anti?)pattern which uses POJOs **only** to carry data from a layer to another in the application (or even outside). Entities are live objects handled by JPA, naming them as Dto is semantically wrong and intrisically dangerous, IMHO.

Comment: *I would like to only select the two values though*: then use your original query, that returns a List<Object[]>, and transfor each array into an actual DTO, i.e. an object containing these two properties only and designed to transfer this data to the client.

Comment: Great advice and explanation! Thanks a lot to both of you!

Comment: @JBNizet : I agree [[5,"sddf"],[3,"asdf"],[2,"gb"],[1,"bg"]] it's a valid JSON but i'm interested in displaying key field as well. Currently it displays only values. How to print key and value pairs like [{id:5,caption:"xyz"},{id:3,caption:"abc"}] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Projections.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces

If this is your Table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name="id")
   private long id;

   @Column(name="caption")
   private String caption;

   @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
   @Column(name="creationDate")
   private Date creationDate;

// .. other columns ..
// ..GETTERS AND SETTERS FOLLOW..
```

Add an Interface-based projections

```
public interface ProjectCaption {
  Long getId();
  String getCaption();
}
```

Then add AS keyword on your query and change the return of your method

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT p.id AS id, p.caption AS caption FROM Project p ORDER BY p.creationDate DESC")
    public List<ProjectCaption> getTimelineProjectCaptions();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your method to something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/timeline", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<ProjectDto>> getTimelineProjectCaptions() {
    return new ResponseEntity<List<ProjectDto>>(projectRepository.getTimelineProjectCaptions(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```